# Custom Field Type - WebEdit Buttons not showing in Experience Editor

Tags: sxa, experience-editor, fieldtype, custom-field

I've created a custom Field Type that's very similar to Rich Text (a Duplicate, in fact) and want to use it with a custom HTML Editor Profile that's similar to Rich Text XA (you guessed it, also a Duplicate but with an added Snippet).

In the Content Editor, it all works as intended, with the HTML Editor showing my custom Snippets, etc, but now I also want the WebEdit buttons that are available for Rich Text XA to show up in the Experience Editor.

**What I'm seeing:**

[image: Custom field type WebEdit Buttons]

**What I want to see:**

[image: Rich Text field type WebEdit Buttons]

When I set the normal Rich Text field to use my custom Editor Profile, all buttons show up as expected, leading me to believe I'm missing some configuration or setting somewhere that enables these buttons for my custom Field Type, but for the life of me I can't find where.

What do I need to do to enable WebEdit buttons for my custom Rich Text-like Field Type?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve that the original field can't do?

Comment: We're adding tokens to to be replaced with facet values à la EXM tokens, but don't want the pipeline to run for every rich text field ever as that could get pretty costly.

Comment: And since the renderField pipeline only knows about the field type we had to solve it this way... Unless you know of a way to figure out what rendering the field is part of in that pipeline, that could also be a solution?